# Reload UI language strings after changing settings

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I have a problem with changing my UI strings after the user has changed the language in the option window. To change the UI strings of the main form, I have to restart the program every time, so that changes take effect, but that's annoying. So I tried it with a delegate to call the function, which loads the strings for the main window in the option window after saving the new settings. The function is called in the option window, but it doesn't change the strings of the main window.

Code in the main window

```
public delegate void CallLoadUIStrings(SupportedLanguages lang);
public CallLoadUIStrings callLoadUIStrings;

public Renamer()
{
     callLoadUIStrings = new CallLoadUIStrings(LoadUIStrings);
}

 public void LoadUIStrings(SupportedLanguages lang)
 {
       try
       {
            switch (lang)
            {
                    #region "DE/JA/FR/ES/NL"
                    case SupportedLanguages.De:
                    case SupportedLanguages.Ja:
                    case SupportedLanguages.Fr:
                    case SupportedLanguages.Es:
                    case SupportedLanguages.Nl:
                         // reads the language file where the ui strings are stored
                        langHelper.Read(RenamerLangOpener.RenamerMainWindow);

                        this.mnuFile.Text = langHelper.Files;
                        this.mnuClose.Text = langHelper.Close;

                        this.mnuEdit.Text = langHelper.Edit;
                        this.mnuUndo.Text = langHelper.Undo;
                        this.mnuCut.Text = langHelper.Cut;
                        this.mnuCopy.Text = langHelper.Copy;
                        this.mnuPaste.Text = langHelper.Paste;
                        this.mnuDelete.Text = langHelper.Delete;
                        this.mnuSelectAll.Text = langHelper.SelectAll;
                     #endregion
            }
       }
       catch (Exception ex) { //exception handling }
}
private void mnuOpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Preferences opt = new Preferences(this);
       opt.ShowDialog();
}
```

Code in the option window

```
    internal Renamer instance = null;
    public Preferences(Renamer form)
    {
        instance = form;
    }
    public void UpdateUI()
    {
        langHelper.ReadSettingsValues();
        instance.BeginInvoke(instance.callLoadUIStrings,new object[] { langHelper.GetLang});
    }
```

Since I've never worked with delegates I don't have a clue where the mistake is.
I've googled so much to find a solution for a similar problem, but I haven't found something that matched my problem.

Comment: can you show that code that opens the Preferences form?

Comment: private void mnuOpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Preferences opt = new Preferences(this);
            opt.ShowDialog();
        }

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is winforms and not WPF question, and that you have one main form that is open from app's Main function. My solution to changing a language is to open this one form in a loop, and continue the loop as long as the form has a property set to some language identifier. If this property is set then I change the language to that value, and go for another loop iteration. I copy all other properties that need be copied form one form to another, with main being the form's position.

If the form is closed without the language ID being set then we break the loop and exit application as usual.